# ReactJS TypeScript pure component with children

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-2015, typescript-typings, tsx

I have a TSX component that is a container wrapping its children like this:

```
import * as React from "react";

interface IProps extends React.Props<Box> {
}

interface IState {
}

export class Box extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Check this out:</h3>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>);
    }
}
```

I also have some pure components, like this one:

```
// ReSharper disable once InconsistentNaming - React components must start with a capital letter.
export function LabelTest(props: { label: string }) {
    return (
        <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
            <label style={{ flex: "1 0 0" }}>{props.label}</label>
            <div style={{ width: "auto" }}>
                This is a pure component.
            </div>
        </div>);
}
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to make a pure container component though. The declaration looks alright and shows no errors:

```
// ReSharper disable once InconsistentNaming - React components must start with a capital letter.
export function LabelBox(props: { label: string, children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <label style={{ flex: "1 0 0" }}>{props.label}</label>
      <div style={{ width: "auto" }}>
        {props.children}
      </div>
    </div>);
}
```

`children` is `React.ReactNode` because that's what it is in `React.Props<X>`.

When used I get *TS2324 Property 'children' is missing in type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { label: string; children: ReactElement | string | number | {} | (Reac...*.

```
// ReSharper disable once InconsistentNaming - React components must start with a capital letter.
export function LabelNumberInput(props: { label: string, value: number }) {
  return (
    <LabelBox label={props.label}>
      <input type="number" value={props.value} />
    </LabelBox>);
}
```

I can't say something like the snippet down below because it will say *Cannot find symbol 'LabelBox' in external module _.tsx* (it's the file in which all of this code is). Doesn't matter if I put the function or the interface first, but it feels wrong overall anyway.

```
interface ILabelBoxProps extends React.Props<LabelBox> { label: string }
export function LabelBox(props: ILabelBoxProps) {
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <label style={{ flex: "1 0 0" }}>{props.label}</label>
      <div style={{ width: "auto" }}>
        {props.children}
      </div>
    </div>);
}
```

What's the right way to make a pure TypeScript React component capable of taking children just like a full class component would? Is this possible? I don't think it should not be, it's still a stateless component and `children` are just a special kind of `props`, really the real problem seems to be the tooling here (Visual Studio) which doesn't map the TSX content node to the `children` prop.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> What's the right way to make a pure TypeScript React component capable of taking children just like a full class component would

Sample :

```
interface PrimitiveProps extends React.HTMLProps<HTMLDivElement>{
   myAdditionalProp:any;
};

export const Content = (allProps: PrimitiveProps) => {
    const {myAdditionalProp, ...props} = allProps;
    return (
        <div data-comment="Content" {...props}/>;
    );
};
```

Of course you are free to do whatever with `myAdditionalProp` and put in more props into `PrimitiveProps` if you want to. Just be sure to remove them from `allProps` before passing it throught. Note that `children` get passed as its a part of `allProps` and thus `props`.

Comment: How did you figure this out? Is there a place I should have looked before asking the question and I missed it? A Google query I didn't think of?

Comment: Experience `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` 

Comment: Thanks for not keeping it to yourself then, you've helped me a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the complete example:

```
interface PaginationItemProps extends React.HTMLProps<HTMLDivElement> {
}

const PaginationItem = (props: PaginationItemProps) => {
   return <div>{props.children}</div>;
}

class Pagination extends React.Component<PaginationProps> {
  render() {
    return <div>          
        <PaginationItem>CHILDREN RENDER</PaginationItem>
    </div>
  }
}
```